# How to suppress window.function calls in a node context, e.g. Not implemented: window.scrollTo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, js-scrollto

A coworker implemented a ScrollToTop component, which has this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window && window.scrollTo && window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}
```

To simply scroll a page to the top in some circumstances.

However, when running tests, the tests periodically error with **Not implemented: window.scrollTo** (full error stack at bottom).

I get that window.scrollTo doesn't exist in a node context, or in the jest tests.  How can I suppress the attempt to scroll in non-browser contexts?  Or how should I handle this global in jest?

```
console.error node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
  Error: Not implemented: window.scrollTo
      at module.exports (/src/argos-r/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/not-implemented.js:9:17)
      at /src/argos-r/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:594:7
      at ScrollToTop.scrollTo [as componentDidMount] (/src/argos-r/src/components/ScrollToTop.js:6:45)
      at commitLifeCycles (/src/argos-r/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17334:22)
      at commitAllLifeCycles (/src/argos-r/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18736:7)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (/src/argos-r/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:149:14)
      at invokeEventListeners (/src/argos-r/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:193:27)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/src/argos-r/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:119:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/src/argos-r/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:82:17)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/src/argos-r/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLElement-impl.js:30:27) undefined
console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
```

Comment: can you not just say `if (window)`

Comment: Wrap the call in a `try/catch`

Comment: you can at the start of the test say window.scrollTo=()=>{} there now its defined and nothing can complain because its a completely new function this way you can even add a hendler in the lambda body in case you wnat to check if it has been called